# Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln x \,dx}{x^b(x+1)}=\pi ^2 \cot(\pi b) \csc(\pi b)$

Tags: improper-integrals

Prove that $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^b(x+1)} dx=\pi ^2 \cot(\pi b) \csc(\pi b)$$ for $0<b<1$.
It is not hard to show it equals to 0 when $b=1/2$, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried contour integral?

Comment: @Hans I would love to but it seems hard to solve directly. Israel's idea might be of help to use contour

Comment: Yes. Israel's integral can be obtained by the contour of a large circle with a slit along the real axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We integrate with $b$ a real from $(0,1)$

$$f(z) = \frac{\mathrm{Log}(z)}{z+1}
\exp(-b\times \mathrm{Log}(z))$$

around a  keyhole contour  with the  slot on  the positive  real axis,
which  is also  where  the  branch cut  of  the  logarithm is  located
(argument of  the logarithm is  between $0$  and $2\pi$). Now  for the
large circle we get $\lim_{R\to\infty} 2\pi R  \log R / R^b /R = 0$ so
there is  no contribution in the  limit.  For the small  circle around
the origin we find $\lim_{\epsilon\to\  0} 2\pi \epsilon \log \epsilon
/ \epsilon^b = \lim_{\epsilon\to\ 0} 2\pi \epsilon^{1-b} \log \epsilon
= 0$ so there is no contribution here either.

We get for the upper line segment

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x+1}
\exp(-b\times \log x) \; dx$$

which is  our target  integral, call  it $J$.  The lower  line segment
contributes

$$-\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x + 2\pi i}{x+1}
\exp(-b\times \log x) \exp(-b\times 2\pi i) \; dx
\\ = - \exp(-b\times 2\pi i)
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x + 2\pi i}{x+1}
\exp(-b\times \log x) \; dx
\\ = - \exp(-b\times 2\pi i)  J
- \exp(-b\times 2\pi i)  2\pi i \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x+1}
\exp(-b\times \log x) \; dx
\\ = - \exp(-b\times 2\pi i)  J
- \exp(-b\times 2\pi i)  2\pi i K.$$

where $J$ and $K$ are real numbers. We thus have

$$(1- \exp(-b\times 2\pi i))J
- \exp(-b\times 2\pi i) 2\pi i K =
2\pi i  \mathrm{Res}_{z=-1} f(z).$$

The residue now yields

$$(1- \exp(-b\times 2\pi i))J
- \exp(-b\times 2\pi i) 2\pi i K =
2\pi i \times \pi i \exp(-b \times \pi i)$$

or

$$(\exp(b\times \pi i) - \exp(-b\times \pi i))J
- \exp(-b\times \pi i) 2\pi i K =
2\pi i \times \pi i$$

and finally

$$\sin(\pi b) J
- \exp(-b\times \pi i) \pi K =
\pi \times \pi i.$$

Using the same contour and the same branch of the logarithm to compute
$K$ we find with

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{z+1}
\exp(-b\times \mathrm{Log}(z))$$

that

$$(1-\exp(-b \times 2\pi i)) K = 2\pi i \times
\mathrm{Res}_{z=-1} g(z)
= 2\pi i \times
\exp(-b \times \pi i)$$

which yields

$$2i \sin(\pi b) K = 2\pi i
\quad\text{so that}\quad
K = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi b)}.$$

Taking the real part of the equation linking $J$ and $K$ we get

$$\sin(\pi b) J - \cos(-\pi b) \frac{\pi^2}{\sin(\pi b)} = 0$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
J = \pi^2 \cot(\pi b) \csc(\pi b)}$$

as claimed.

Comment: Thanks for your patient instruction. It is elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\dfrac{1}{1+x}=u$ then
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^b(x+1)} dx 
&= -\dfrac{d}{db}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^b(x+1)} dx \\
&= -\dfrac{d}{db}\int_0^1 u^{b-1}(1-u)^{-b} du \\
&= -\dfrac{d}{db}\left(\Gamma(b)\Gamma(1-b)\right) \\
&= -\dfrac{d}{db}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{\sin\pi b}\right) \\
&= \color{blue}{\pi ^2 \cot\pi b\csc\pi b}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You might start with $$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{dx}{x^b(x+1)}  = \pi \csc(\pi b)$$
and differentiate with respect to $b$.

Comment: Thx, let me have a try. But you have double "dx" there.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for noticing.